# Android project: This job is stuck, because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it. Go to Runners page

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an issue with running Gitlab CI, source code below:

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - package

#####################################################################
# BUILD
#
.build_template: &build_template_def
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 4 hours
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
    - .android/

  before_script:
# Extract the SDK version that we're building against
- export ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK=`egrep '^[[:blank:]]+compileSdkVersion'  app/build.gradle | awk '{print $2}'`

# Explict output for logging purpose only
- echo $ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS
- echo $ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK

# Fetch the specified SDK tools version to build with
- wget --quiet --output-document=/tmp/sdk-tools-linux.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
- unzip /tmp/sdk-tools-linux.zip -d .android

# Set up environment variables
- export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/.android
- export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/.android/platform-tools/

# Install platform tools and Android SDK for the compile target
- echo y | .android/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}"

- chmod +x ./gradlew

build_debug:
  <<: *build_template_def
  tags:
   - buildtag
  only:
    - develop
    - tags
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug

build_release:
  <<: *build_template_def
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Even after addition of tags to the jobs, it is saying that stuck.
Also tried changing:
variables:

ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "27"

ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "27.0.3"

ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"

Anybody who faced this issue, especially for android project.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it?